# How to animate shrinking and growing of two elements at the same time?

Tags: react-native

I want to create a weekly plan and the user should be able to "select" a day which should then grow in the ui (example below).
I am using the Animated class from react-native and noticed I am not able to animate the flex-property, so I believe I have to do this using width and height.

[image]

[image]

I tried the following after reading @M.N.s awnser:

```
  selectDay = (i: number) => {
    const {selected, grow, shrink} = this.state;

    this.setState({selected: i, latestSelected: selected});
    grow.setValue(0.5);
    shrink.setValue(1);

    Animated.parallel(
      [
        Animated.timing(grow, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 200,
          useNativeDriver: false,
          easing: Easing.cubic,
        }),
        Animated.timing(shrink, {
          toValue: 0.5,
          duration: 200,
          useNativeDriver: false,
          easing: Easing.cubic,
        }),
      ],
      {stopTogether: false},
    ).start();
  };

// In my render:
const growInterpolate = grow.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: ['0%', '25%'],
});

const shrinkInterpolate = shrink.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: ['0%', '25%'],
});
```

But it still behaves very laggy:
[Video of the animation](https://www.veed.io/view/bfb3668b-7164-4072-945a-0f5b259f81e8)

Answer (score 0):

In such case you need to use parallel animation:

```
Animated.parallel([
  Animated.timing(animatedHeight, {
    toValue: newHeight,
    duration: 200,
  }),
  Animated.timing(animatedWidth, {
    toValue: newWidth,
    duration: 200,
  })
], { stopTogether: false }).start()
```

More information:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#parallel